# Querying DataSet in memory using LINQ vs querying SQL Table directly (dictionary table) - performance

Tags: sql-server, linq, memory, datatable

I found no exact answer yet, so:

Imagine a 3-column dictionary table structured following way:

> int | string1 | string2  (where int+string1 is pk)

Table has more than 20k rows and it's queried very extensively by its `pk` to return `string2` value

What would be the best approach here?

**1.** Direct LINQ DB request

**pro:** query by PK which indeed is very fast

**cons:** possibly few hundred calls per sec to db server

**2.** Preload data once to DataTable object

**pro:** All data is in local .net memory (no need to go every time to db)

**cons:** usage of LINQ requires calling `AsEnumerable()` on `DataTable` which returns enumerable object as `DataSource` for LINQ query. Is LINQ query on object more efficient here than calling DB? is PK constraint used here?

**3.** Preload all table to `Dictionary<string, string>` where key is `int.ToString()+string1` and value `string2`

**pro:** PK constraint always used and dictionary responds directly with correct value

**cons:** Is is it better than 1 or 2?

**4.** Your better idea

My great curiosity awaits answers...

Comment: These type of performance questions rely very heavily on the actual requirements and usage, which none of us knows.  We have a similar type of situation in our code base, where an id translation table is stored in a database.  Since the translation table drives around 1500 lookups for a single process, I made the judgment to preload all the data into a dictionary (which can be as big as 200k+ rows).  However, that decision was made *only* by trying out each option and comparing the performance in lots of real-world scenarios.

Comment: I fully agree with what you're writing. I'd like to code all 3 examples and test performance but the problem here is always time.
I've used no1 for now as it took few sec to implement. Hopefully I'll have some time later to check on all three examples...

Comment: You also have to keep in mind the technical complexity that comes with caching anything - keeping the data in sync if other processes are also writing data to the back-end table.  Remember, "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." :)  I will say it's not really that hard to download the data into a table and look there instead.  It really should only take part of a day to implement both option 2 and 3 and try them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got a moment to write a simple test application, but using the real data, so the results are very relevant in this case.

So - once I preloaded around 4k records to Dictionary and did 100k loops over with result of retrieving the data **00:00:00.950095** !!

Second time I did same 100k loops asking database every single time with following result: **00:02:32.81...**

Seems the choice is easy.